# Jquery search filter same ul li list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have ul li list the search filter div also in same li list and those coming dynamically so there are multiple ul li list on page when i filter the li list its not working or filtering the list

My code

```
<ul>
<li><div><input class="FilterSearch" type="text"/></div></li>
<li>Abc</li>
<li>rtp</li>
<li>mht</li>
<li>Abc</li>
<li>weq</li>
<li>pio</li>
<li>cca</li>
<li>asas</li>
</ul>


$(document).on("input propertychange paste change", '.FilterSearch', function (e) {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(this).parent().siblings().find('li').filter(function () {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of below logic where you can hide all `li`s first and then `filter` each li and show it only when it contains the search text.

```js
$(document).on("input propertychange paste change", '.FilterSearch', function(e) {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  var $ul = $(this).closest('ul');
  //get all lis but not the one having search input
  var $li = $ul.find('li:gt(0)');
  //hide all lis
  $li.hide();
  $li.filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    return text.indexOf(value)>=0;
  }).show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div><input class="FilterSearch" type="text" /></div>
  </li>
  <li>Abc</li>
  <li>rtp</li>
  <li>mht</li>
  <li>Abc</li>
  <li>weq</li>
  <li>pio</li>
  <li>cca</li>
  <li>asas</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent of your `input` is `div` and it has no siblings. So search for parents `ul` element and find all `li` but not the first one where your `input` is

```
$(this).parents("ul").find('li:not(li:first-of-type)').filter(function() {
```

```js
$(document).on("input propertychange paste change", '.FilterSearch', function(e) {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $(this).parents("ul").find('li:not(li:first-of-type)').filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div><input class="FilterSearch" type="text" /></div>
  </li>
  <li>Abc</li>
  <li>rtp</li>
  <li>mht</li>
  <li>Abc</li>
  <li>weq</li>
  <li>pio</li>
  <li>cca</li>
  <li>asas</li>
</ul>
```